# RecordView doesn't show up

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xamarin.android

I added recordView library [1]: https://github.com/3llomi/RecordView in order to make it possible for the users to send voice recorded messages, but when I click the button to record the recordview doesn't show up. Here is the code and the Logcat error:

Code:

```
private void initView() {

        recordBtn.setOnRecordClickListener(new OnRecordClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "RECORD BUTTON CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("RecordButton","RECORD BUTTON CLICKED");


                recordBtn.setListenForRecord(true);


                recordView.setOnRecordListener(new OnRecordListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        Log.d("RecordView", "onStart");

                        setUpRecording();

                        try {
                            mediaRecorder.prepare();
                            mediaRecorder.start();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        recordView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d("RecordView", "onCancel");

                        mediaRecorder.reset();
                        mediaRecorder.release();
                        File file = new File(recordPath);
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            file.delete();
                        }
                        recordView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish(long recordTime) {
                        Log.d("RecordView", "onFinish");

                        mediaRecorder.stop();
                        mediaRecorder.release();
                        recordView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        sendRecordingMessage(recordPath);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLessThanSecond() {
                        Log.d("RecordView", "onLessThanSecond");

                        mediaRecorder.reset();
                        mediaRecorder.release();
                        recordView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });


    }

    private void setUpRecording() {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "chats");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        recordPath = file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".3gp";

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(recordPath);
    }


    private void sendRecordingMessage(String recordPath) {
        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("recordings");
        Uri recordFile = Uri.fromFile(new File(recordPath));
        storageReference.putFile(recordFile).addOnSuccessListener(success->{
            Task<Uri> recordUrl = success.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();

            recordUrl.addOnCompleteListener(path->{
                if (path.isSuccessful()) {
                    String url = path.getResult().toString();
                    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    Chat messageModel = new Chat(firebaseUser.getUid(), userId, util.currentData(), "recordings", true);
                    reference.push().setValue(messageModel);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Logcat:

```
2021-03-08 22:47:38.793 9176-9176/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallVoidMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
        at void android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(int) (MediaRecorder.java:-2)
        at void com.example.selfcial.Activities.MessageActivity.setUpRecording() (MessageActivity.java:580)
        at void com.example.selfcial.Activities.MessageActivity.access$1000(com.example.selfcial.Activities.MessageActivity) (MessageActivity.java:77)
        at void com.example.selfcial.Activities.MessageActivity$12$1.onStart() (MessageActivity.java:528)
        at void com.devlomi.record_view.RecordView.onActionDown(com.devlomi.record_view.RecordButton, android.view.MotionEvent) (RecordView.java:188)
        at boolean com.devlomi.record_view.RecordButton.onTouch(android.view.View, android.view.MotionEvent) (RecordButton.java:104)
        at boolean android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (View.java:13479)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2724)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2724)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2724)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2724)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2724)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2724)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2724)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2724)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2724)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2724)
        at boolean com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (DecorView.java:496)
        at boolean com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (PhoneWindow.java:1853)
        at boolean android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Activity.java:4059)
        at boolean androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at boolean com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (DecorView.java:454)
      at boolean
```

Any ideas on how can this be solved?

Comment: are you using a physical device? remember that record audio is not supported by the emulator, the documentation says that

Comment: @ruif3r Yes, I use my smartphone